# use mpi_cart_create with master and slave

Tags: fortran, mpi, topology

I want to create a topology without 0 processor in it. My idea is to make processor 0 as master and create topology as slave. After certain computation sin topology, I will send data to master. Here is my code:

```
      include "mpif.h"

      integer   maxn

      integer   myid,Root,numprocs,numtasks,taskid
      integer   comm2d, ierr
      integer   dims(2)
      logical   periods(2)
      data periods/2*.false./
    Root = 0
      CALL MPI_INIT( ierr )
      CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr )
      CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr )
      numtasks = numprocs-1
      if(myid .eq. Root) then
      print *, 'Hello I am master'
      endif
c  Get a new communicator for a decomposition of the domain.  
c  Let MPI find a "good" decomposition
      dims(1) = 0
      dims(2) = 0
      CALL MPI_DIMS_CREATE(numtasks,2,dims,ierr)
      CALL MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,2,dims,periods,.true.,
     *                    comm2d,ierr)
c   Get my position in this communicator
      CALL MPI_COMM_RANK( comm2d, taskid, ierr )        
c
    print *, 'task ID= ',taskid
    if (myid .eq. master) then
        print *,dims(1),dims(2)
    endif
      CALL MPI_Comm_free( comm2d, ierr )

30    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

      STOP
      END
```

But, when I run above code; I am getting the following error.

> Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
>   PMPI_Comm_rank(121): MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x7fff08bf960c)
>   failed PMPI_Comm_rank(73).: Null communicator

How can I eliminate the error? What I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think, I have edited it now..

Comment: Any reason for developing new code in 2016 using Fortran77 standard?

Comment: @ Gilles not exactly learning MPI it is picked from a tutorial.

Comment: @ Vladimir, I have edited it. Actually I am confused on editing code in stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't ask us to debug Fortran code lacking `implicit none`.  Don't waste your own time on such code either.

Comment: This tutorial you are picking from must be really old and outdated. The use of MPI's `mpif.h` Fortran interface is **strongly discouraged**. Even the `use mpi` interface is falling out of grace. Learn modern Fortran and stick to an MPI implementation that provides the `use mpi_f08` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start your MPI job with `numprocs` processes. Then you create a Cartesian topology with `numtasks = numprocs-1` processes. Therefore, one of the processes ends up not being part of the Cartesian communicator and receives `MPI_COMM_NULL` in `comm2d`. Calling `MPI_COMM_RANK` with a null communicator is an error. The solution is to fix your code to first check the value of `comm2d`:

```
 CALL MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,2,dims,periods,.true.,
*                     comm2d,ierr)
 IF (comm2d.NE.MPI_COMM_NULL) THEN
   ...
 ENDIF
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hristo, I will give feed back tomorrow.

Comment: yes it is working now. The cart processors are having ranks from 0 to numtasks..How would I handle to run computations here and send data to slave whose rank is zero. As rank 0 is repeating twice; This pushed me into one more doubt.

Comment: Rank 0 in the Cartesian communicator has a different rank in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. The master process cannot send messages in `comm2d` anyway as it is not member of the communicator.